# Chromecast event for device disconnect (sender)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cast, chromecast

Is there event that will notify a sender app when the use selects "stop cast" from within the chrome extension?

I've a chrome sender app get's in a limbo state if the user chooses to stop the cast from the extension instead of the app cast button.

EDIT:
This is some relevant code:

```
CastPlayer.prototype.onMediaDiscovered = function (how, mediaSession) {
  this.currentMediaSession = mediaSession;
  // ...    
  this.currentMediaSession.addUpdateListener(this.onMediaStatusUpdate.bind(this));
  // ...
};

CastPlayer.prototype.onMediaStatusUpdate = function (e) {
  console.log(e);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [`Session.addUpdateListener(listener)`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#addUpdateListener) ? I think the listener will be notified when the session is no longer alive.

Comment: Thank you for the input, currently I do bind a listener to the session, the same listener works as expected when terminating the session with `this.session.stop()` but it won't receive anything when closing the session using the extension. I've added some code to the question maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: From the look of the code that you posted, it seems like you were referring to the Media Session and a listener there. If that is the case, that listener only gets notified about the state of media and changes there. I was referring to the Session and the listener on that  (see the link to the method I have in my previous answer). Are you referring to the same?

Comment: That's true! I haven't realise there is Media Session, could you please point me to documentation about that? From what I can see in documentation [loadMedia](http://goo.gl/UHF7Xv) successCallback is a function will pass chrome.cast.media.Media as parameter `function(chrome.cast.media.Media)`, this is confusing! as from the code example pointed in @angel-custodio answer you can see that the handler function [updates a variable](http://goo.gl/Z7N6r8) `this.currentMediaSession` with the parameter `mediaSession`. Apart from my doubts this plus the code example solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It seems Google developers are pretty aware of that! :D
They've just update their senders sample code with a commit that is exactly what seems you're looking for: [Added session update listener to handle disconnect by clicking cast extension](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome/commit/c1ed2f442adbf84b3f00230d69cc85b7d75222a2)

There's also another commit with the same text in another sample but with less code, here you have: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome/commit/776559c9aaf16d7d82c62ee4dea611b6177ac217

Comment: Thank you for the code example, it helps to complete the answer provided by @ali-naddaf